# Why no automatic simplification?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why isn't the last statement simplified? Is it a bug in 11.1.1.0?

```
Product[1 - 1/Prime[n]^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]
FullSimplify[(1 - 1/Prime[n]) (1 + 1/Prime[n])]
Product[%, {n, 1, Infinity}]
Product[(1 - 1/Prime[n]) (1 + 1/Prime[n]), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider the fact that Mathematica can't compute everything that can be computed a bug ... Functions like `Product` use heuristics. It's not uncommon that helping them along a bit allows finding a solution they can't get on their own. (That said, it may be worth reporting to WRI. Only the developers will be able to tell if this behaviour is as it should be, or whether this is an easy opportunity for improvement.)

Comment: @Szabolcs, I usually give hints as needed. Make your comment an answer and I will sign off on it. Thanks.

Comment: I also found that the first-time evaluate of that last expression takes about 10s (with the kernel already running so it's not startup time, and subsequent evaluations take ~10^-4 s). Curious as to what it's doing during that time.

Comment: It isn't exactly a bug, so if you do report, please mention that this is a suggestion.

Comment: @J.M., I just reported it as a suggestion for a small improvement.

Comment: `Product[(1 - 1/Prime[n]) (1 + 1/Prime[n]) // FullSimplify, {n, 1, 
  Infinity}]` seems to give an answer pretty rapidly.

Comment: @bills - or use `Simplify` or `Expand`

Comment: @J.M., From WRI support: I have filed your suggestion with our developers. Thank you for taking the time to report it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied my last comment to create an answer to close this thread.

From WRI support: I have filed your suggestion with our developers. Thank you for taking the time to report it.